# How to change highcharts' data name dynamically?

Tags: highcharts

I don't want to use the following code.

```
charts.update(~);
//or
charts.series[0].update(~);
```

For exmaple, we can change the data, title and yaxis with below codes, but I couldn't fine how to the name. How can I change the name without update function?

```
charts.setTitle({text: 'aaa'});
chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({ text: 'bbb' });
```

Comment: If you want to update the name without using the update function, then you will have to change several attributes. Look at the console when you press the button in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/04Lyej57/.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "data name"? Name of the series or name of the point?

Comment: @ Kamil Kulig, I mean name of series

Comment: @ewolden, I checked the console with your example code in fiddle, but I could not change the name.